# не добавляется двоеточие в sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, ip

хочу добавить ip адреса в sql server через php запросом, не получается (наверное из за двоеточие) в таблице Users столбец user_ip тип данных nvarchar(300)

```
$userip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query= ("update Users set user_ip=(".$userip.") where id= (".$_SESSION['login'].")");
```

[image: ответ ошибки]

Comment: параметризация SQL запросов

Comment: Знаете, в SQL запросах есть большая разница между `192.168.0.1` и `'192.168.0.1'`. Советую и вам в этом разобраться

Comment: а str_replace поможет?

Comment: вам поможет заключение подставляемых строковых значений в одинарные кавычки. тем не менее как указано в первом комментарии, изучите как работает биндинг параметров запроса для используемого драйвера доступа к БД